# Why does looking through an LCD panel make things blurry?

Tags: optics

When you take the back off an LCD panel and remove the backlight, you are left with a translucent panel. But when I look *through* the panel, even in its "clear" state, objects look blurry. Why is this? Shouldn't they just be dimmer, as the front polarizer blocks half of the light? Is diffraction to blame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the backlight to be diffuse and even. That is not simple. If you look at a lamp of any kind you don't just see an evenly bright area. A diffuser is needed to make a uniformly bright spot. An everyday example of such a diffuser is fog. Or your hand if you look at a red light through it. Another good example is a lightbox, a box with lamps in it and ground glass on it, that people used to look at negatives or photographic slides.

Comment: I see, so you're saying that there's a diffuser built into the back side of the LCD panel. That makes a lot of sense.